# Huge differences in Jmeter starttime and webservices entry point starttime on openshift

Tags: jmeter, openshift

I am doing load test to see performance using JMeter. My webservices deployed on OpenShift.
I was checking the starttime of Jmeter and STarttime of Webservice entry point of that particular transaction has some milliseconds differences(sometime it has more than 1s difference also).
Can you please let me know what could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "starttime"

JMeter acts as follows:

- Sends requests
- Waits for the response
- Measures the time in-between

If your JMeter instance is geographically in the different location than the OpenShift instance it might take some time for request to travel around the globe (see [Connect Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) and [Latency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Understanding_latency) metrics) so if you're in Japan and the server is in France - the request will have to pass via hundreds or routers

So if you want to get more closer results you need to deploy JMeter in more close [geo location](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-regions-and-zones&locale=en) and preferably on OpenShift as well

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Understanding Your Reports: Part 3 - Key Statistics Performance Testers Need to Understand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-3-key-statistics-performance-testers-need-understand)